# C# WinApi - Key up not working

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, keypress

I am trying to send keypresses to multiple windows at once. I have made a method to find the windows I need, and I have confirmed that it works. My problem is, that the keys I send get stuck.

Here I am sending the key 'W', this works. The problem is that the key never gets released. I have tried to fix this in multiple ways, but I can't seem to fix it for the life of me.

**Edit:** It seems that when I call SendMessage(Window, 0x0101, ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0); it presses the key down instead of up, although the documentation clearly states that WM_KEYUP is 0x0101.

**TL;DR how do I release a key with WinApi?**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This part works, method is uneccessary to know
        List<IntPtr> Windows = FindWindows("Minecraft 1.8.7").ToList();

        foreach (IntPtr win in Windows)
            SendKeyPress((ushort)Keys.W, win);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static void SendKeyPress(ushort k, IntPtr Window)
    {
        //I tried with 0x0101 and 0x0100 aswell
        const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x018;
        const uint SC_CLOSE = 0x053;

        //I tried with PostMessage
        //I also tried putting a sleep statement between these two:
        SendMessage(Window, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0);
        SendMessage(Window, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be sending the messages too fast, try inserting a short delay between them and see if that helps.

Comment: You mean after each keypress is sent? I tried adding a whole second delay, nothing. My theory is that the keypresses sent are activating the check for keypresses, thus creating an infinite loop. If this is the case, I don't know how to combat it.

Comment: I mean between the two `SendMessage` calls in the method `SendKeyPress`.

Comment: Tried it, nothing. If you look at the edit, there is a fundamental issue. Calling keyup actually presses the key down. Therefore I currently have no way to release keys; `SendMessage(Window, 0x0101, ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is **not** how you automate a GUI. You automate a GUI by using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). That way you won't need to pile hack on top of another hack, that tries to solve adverse effects of other hacks piled on top of yet other hacks.

Comment: Where did you read that this was the way to automate an external application? I would love to know why so many people start down this path.